# How to avoid scientific notation in log-log plot after customising the font in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I use font_manager to customise the font of tick label. However, the tick label is displayed with scientific notation, e.g. 1e-10 in y-axis shown in the attached figure. How to avoid this scientific notation after customising the font and visualise it naturally as it shows in x-axis?

[image]

The code for this plot is

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.loglog(10**-10, 10**-10)

from matplotlib import font_manager as fm
from matplotlib import rcParams
prop = fm.FontProperties(fname=rcParams["datapath"] + "/fonts/ttf/Helvetica.ttf")
ax.set_yticklabels(ax.get_yticks(), fontProperties=prop)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no good API for setting the font properties to axis labels. One might expect there to be an option inside `ax.tick_params` - however that is not the case currently.

Options you have:

```
plt.setp(ax.get_yticklabels(), fontProperties=prop)
```

or

```
for l in ax.get_yticklabels():
    l.set_fontproperties(prop)
```

Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import font_manager as fm

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.loglog(10**-10, 10**-10)


prop = fm.FontProperties("Arial")
plt.setp(ax.get_yticklabels(), fontProperties=prop)

plt.show()
```